# How can I display queryset values by x in group?

Tags: python, django

How can I display queryset values by x in group?

```
qs = Item.objects.all() # 12 items
count = len(qs)

if count > 5:
    for item in qs[:5]:
        print item
    # now I need to display the rest(next 5 items and later 2 items) of results.
    # something like this: for item in qs[5:10] and next for item in qs[10:12] 
    # BUT I don't know how many items will be in queryset. This is only example.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'*display queryset values by x in group'* - This concept is referred as **PAGINATION**.

You can use **[Django Paginator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/)** to paginate querysets.

> It manages paginated data – that is, data that’s split across several
>   pages, with “Previous/Next” links. These classes live in
>   `django/core/paginator.py`.
>
> Give Paginator a list of objects, plus the number of items you’d like
>   to have on each page, and it gives you methods for accessing the items
>   for each page.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

qs = Item.objects.all()
p = Paginator(qs, 5) # 5 is the no. of elements to be displayed each time

# To get total no of pages i.e. no. of times result have to be displayed
total_pages = p.num_pages

# print page 1
for item in p.page(1).object_list:
    print item  

# print page 2
for item in p.page(2).object_list:
    print item
```

You can even convert this  process of printing objects into a function and just pass it a paginator object and a page no.

Sort of like below:

```
def display_queryset_values(paginator_object, page_no=1):
    for item in paginator_object.page(page_no).object_list:
        print item  

display_queryset_values(p, 1) #Displays 1st 5 objects 
display_queryset_values(p, 2) #Displays next 5 objects
```

**A sample example(taken from [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/pagination/#example)):**

```
>>> from django.core.paginator import Paginator
>>> objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
>>> p = Paginator(objects, 2)

>>> p.count
4
>>> p.num_pages
2
>>> p.page_range
[1, 2]

>>> page1 = p.page(1)
>>> page1
<Page 1 of 2>
>>> page1.object_list
['john', 'paul']

>>> page2 = p.page(2)
>>> page2.object_list
['george', 'ringo']
>>> page2.has_next()
False
>>> page2.has_previous()
True
>>> page2.has_other_pages()
True
>>> page2.next_page_number()
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
EmptyPage: That page contains no results

>>> p.page(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
EmptyPage: That page number is less than 1
>>> p.page(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
EmptyPage: That page contains no results
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the length is not an issue. Python can do that for you, all you need to know is the start and end.

When [slicing the list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), if the end is greater than the number of elements, python will print it till the end of the list.

**Example**

```
>>> a_list = range(12)
>>> no_items_per_loop = 5
>>> end = 5
>>> while a_list[ end - no_items_per_loop : end ]:
...     print a_list[ end - no_items_per_loop : end ]
...     end += no_items_per_loop
... 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python it does not matter where the end of your slice is:

```
a = [0,1]

print a[0:2]
# [0,1]

print a[0:5]
# [0,1]
```

So in your case you could step over the list:

```
item_count = len(items)
i = 0
while i < item_count:
    print items[i:i+5]
    i += 5
```